# VS 2012 RTM Intellisense Broken

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

This seems to be happening on a project-by-project basis. Currently I am working on an ASP.NET 4.5 Web Application Project. Intellisense was fine one day but not the next. I am using a custom project template but that should make no difference.  I tried editing the text editor settings so that Auto list members and Parameter information are both checked. I tried to reset your Visual Studio settings (Tools --> Import and export settings --> Reset all settings) and I also tried the solution in the accepted answer here:

[Intellisense not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518526/intellisense-not-working)

Has anyone got any insight or suggestions? Pending any answers, I've submitted a Connect bug report: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/766891/intellisense-broken-in-vs-2012-rtm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be able to refresh Intellisense cache with Ctrl + Shift + R (on standard shortcut keys)

I've had the same issue on VS2010 and fixed it another method described at [How to turn IntelliSense on in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902232/how-to-turn-intellisense-on-in-visual-studio-2010)

From the link:

1. Delete the files in this folder: `%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ReflectedSchemas` (the 10.0 folder may be a different number for VS2012)
2. If nothing else works, you type this in the Visual Studio Command Prompt (this is in your Start menu) and hit enter: `devenv /resetuserdata`

This last option is [documented here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb245788%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#vs05idetips_topic6), with the following disclaimer:

> Disclaimer: you will lose all your environment settings and
>   customizations if you use this switch. It is for this reason that this
>   switch is not officially supported and Microsoft does not advertise
>   this switch to the public (you won't see this switch if you type
>   devenv.exe /? in the command prompt). You should only use this switch
>   as the last resort if you are experiencing an environment problem, and
>   make sure you back up your environment settings by exporting them
>   before using this switch.

Comment: I've updated my answer to what fixed it for me a few weeks back in VS2010

Comment: Per your link, Edit -> Intellisense -> Refresh Remote References, for some reason fixed it!

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked. Losing intelisense is annoying. I didn't mention that method in the link since that menu doesn't appear in my VS2010. Odd

Comment: Thanks! the second option worked for me after restarting VS2012 numerous times and rebooting my computer.